# PresentationCore/PresnetationFramwork cause a problem when added in reference

Tags: visual-studio, reference, f#

Part of the f# code

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Windows.Media.Imaging

type GameControl() as this = 
    inherit UserControl()
    let x = "...
```

and here the refernces i have

- FSharp.Core
- mscorlib
- System
- System.Numerics
- System.ValueTupie

I have red lines under

- Controls
- Media
- Media(the second one with Imaging)

so, when i add `PresentationFramework.dll` and i get `PresentationCore` and `PresnetationFramwork` in the list

after adding PresnetationFramwork to references

i get red lines under

- Imaging
- GameControl(which it was working before)
- x(which it was working before)

i added PresentationCore to refrences and all the code became red and it fixed when i delete `open System.Windows` but still GameControl and x in red

I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Appreciate any help and sorry for the bad english

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Windows`?

Comment: @Asti sorry for the late, yes i added that, here's the codes, it's pacman game http://www.fssnip.net/raw/9V

http://www.fssnip.net/raw/cZ

Comment: @Asti i really spent hours trying to run one of that games without success, hope you can do it in your end